# Log4net logs are not getting updated on Windows Server 2012 until service restart

Tags: c#, windows-services, log4net, windows-server-2012

I am using log4net for logging in my windows service, it is working fine on XP, 7, 8, Windows Server 2003.

But when it comes to Windows 2012 server (also contains SQL server 2012 in it) log4net is not logging/updating the logs.

Log file is not updating after performing some operations in windows service. It needs restart of windows service to update the logs. Last/recent logs can be seen only after service restart.

```
     <log4net>
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="Log\MyLog_" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd.lo\g" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="6" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <!--<conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline%exception"/>-->
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date %-5level %-60logger - %-10message%newline%exception" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="SnFApp" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="Log\MyLog1_" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd.lo\g" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="6" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <!--<conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline%exception"/>-->
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date %-5level %-60logger - %-10message%newline%exception" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<logger name="TransactionManager.SaFManager.ClCCTaMPOSSaFManager">
  <appender-ref ref="SnFApp" />
</logger>
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
</root>
<logger name="Log4NetTest.OtherClass">
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
</logger>
```

Comment: could you provide logger configuration?

Comment: Added log4net configuration in my question, not able to add here.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm concerned, it locks file exclusively by default. Could you try if this helps?

`<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />`

We've got it running on 2012 Server, too, without this issue.

Comment: starteleport, you are saying " it locks file exclusively by default.", then it should behave same on all platforms, right? But it is working fine and log file is getting updated on 2003.

If we have to try above then could you please let me know where should I place <lockingModel> tag

Comment: @SujeetSaste: place it under corresponding `<appender>`

Comment: Ok will check it. Currently I have no same environment available to test. Will update here once get chance to test it.

Comment: @SujeetSaste, have you tried it? Please share your results.

Comment: i have not tried it due to limitations of platform availability.

Comment: @starteleport - I encountered the same issue as explained in this thread. your suggestion worked like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you see the following behavior on Windows 2012 server, the logging is working, only the file timestamp is not updated:

[file-date-modified-property-are-not-updating-while-modifying-a-file-without-closing-it](http://blogs.technet.com/b/asiasupp/archive/2010/12/14/file-date-modified-property-are-not-updating-while-modifying-a-file-without-closing-it.aspx)

> These days, we are monitoring this issue: when one was developing a
>   utility that monitors log files as they are updated.
>
> On 2003, opening the log file folder in explorer, you can see the
>   timestamp and files size change before your eyes each time the log is
>   updated.
>
> On 2008, "Last Modified" field on log files is not updated unless
>   another  program attempts to open the file or the utility is stopped,
>   even if F5 is pressed to  refresh the view.
>
> Explorer gets is information from NTFS, by using a cmd prompt and
>   "dir" we found that the NTFS metadata for the files is not updated
>   until the handle to a file is closed.

Comment: Thanks for the link you shared.
It simply means if utility is writing log file (it is opened by utility) and because of that log file size is not changing as well as the date modified is also not updated. It is not an issue at utility but OS functionality causing this.